# Turning off monitor as root, without xset

Tags: hardware, monitors

I have a script in `/etc/acpi` that runs when I close my laptop's lid.
It turns off the internal monitor.  It does this by

```
                export DISPLAY=:0
                sudo -u toothrot xset dpms force off
```

This works fine, but it would be neater if it didn't depend on my
being logged in as toothrot.  Is there a way to do it directly from root,
without reference to a particular X-session?  I tried

```
            # echo Off >/sys/class/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/dpms
```

but got `permission denied`.

Note that setting the brightness to 0 will not do, since it doesn't
save any power.

Comment: Have you done it as root?

Comment: Obviously the that one wont work. I am asking about the echo.

Comment: On my FreeBSD I use `vbetool dpms off`, as Debian also has a vbetool package I guess it's not FreeBSD-specific.

Comment: @Henrik, I have vbetool, but for some reason that doesn't do anything on my system.

Comment: If your X server is being run with `-auth /some/file` then you should be able to run as root, eg `DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/some/file xset ...`

Comment: @meuh, this works, but is still with reference to the x-session.